# Why are fields being required in my SOAP call?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

This is my `WSDL`: https://secure-wms.com/webserviceexternal/contracts.asmx?WSDL and the corresponding docs: http://app02.3plcentral.com/WebServiceExternal/Contracts.asmx?op=CreateOrders

I'm trying to Submit a `CreateOrders` SOAP call in PHP using `SoapClient`, but it keeps telling me to include more and more fields:

```
Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'FulfillmentSalePrice' property
```

`FulfillmentSalePrice` is not required, so why is it making me submit?

My call looks like:

```
$createOrderArray = array(
  'Order'    =>  array(
    'TransInfo'       =>  array(
      'ReferenceNum'    =>  '123',
      'PONum'           =>  '1234',
      'EarliestShipDate' => time(),
      'ShipCancelDate' => time() + 60000,
    ),
    'ShipTo'          =>  array(
      'Name'            =>  "John Smith",
      'Address'         =>  array(
        'Address1'        =>  '123 Main Street',
        'Address2'        =>  '',
        'City'            =>  'Monroe',
        'State'           =>  'NJ',
        'Zip'             =>  '08831',
        'Country'         =>  'USA',
      ),
      'PhoneNumber'   =>  '732-1234-2408',
      'EmailAddress1' =>  'email@address.com',
      'CustomerName'  =>  'John Smith',
      'RetailerID'    =>  ''
    ),
    'ShippingInstructions'  =>  array(
      'Carrier'               =>  "USPS",
      'Mode'                  =>  "First Class Mail",
      'BillingCode'           =>  "Prepaid"
    ),
    'PalletCount'     =>  1,
    'Notes'           =>  '',
    'OrderLineItems'  =>  array(
      'OrderLineItem'   =>  array(
        'SKU'             =>  "1234",
        'Qualifier'       =>  '',
        'Qty'             =>  1,

        'Packed'          =>  '',
        'CuFtPerCarton'   =>  '',
        'ExpirationDate'   =>  '',
      )
    )
  ),
);


$session = $client->CreateOrders($extLoginData, $createOrderArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FulfillmentSalePrice has `minOccurs="1"` set in the wsdl, so is required.

Let me know if you run into any other errors and we'll troubleshoot together.

Comment: So if I use a local copy of the WSDL, I can set it to not required?  According to their support, it isn't a required field

Comment: The WSDL is really used as a reference for what their API endpoint expects.  You could add the `FulfillmentSalePrice` as an empty parameter in your $createOrderArray variable.  Give that a try and let me know how you get on.

Comment: Then I have to add every field as an empty parameter, no?

Comment: In your `OrderLineItem`, add a new key => value pair for `FulfillmentSalePrice` like `FulfillmentSalePrice => ''`. Am I missing something?  As far as I know, you need to include every attribute that has a minOccurs=1 set.